# AngularJS - how to use factory inside a provider

Tags: angularjs

I wonder how can i use factory inside a provider for using it inside config.

Since i understand config can be injected only with providers - i wonder how can i achieve the following functionality

```
app.provider('getUserLanguageProvider',['$injector', function($injector) {

    this.$get = function(getUserLang) {  // calling a factory 
    
        var userLang = getUserLang.getLang()
        return {
            getLang: function() {
                return userLang
            }
        }
    };

    
}]);

app.config(['$translateProvider', 'getUserLanguageProvider', function ($translateProvider, getUserLanguageProvider) {
     
    const lang = getUserLanguageProvider.getLang() // get the language key from provider

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage(lang); // set the language key brought by getUserLang.getLang() factory
    
    
}]);
```

I've tried many versions of what i've described - but none works.

Comment: What error did you get when you tried this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't append `Provider` to the provider name. Simply use the name of the service:

```
̶a̶p̶p̶.̶p̶r̶o̶v̶i̶d̶e̶r̶(̶'̶g̶e̶t̶U̶s̶e̶r̶L̶a̶n̶g̶u̶a̶g̶e̶P̶r̶o̶v̶i̶d̶e̶r̶'̶,̶[̶'̶$̶i̶n̶j̶e̶c̶t̶o̶r̶'̶,̶ ̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶$̶i̶n̶j̶e̶c̶t̶o̶r̶)̶ ̶{̶  
app.provider('getUserLanguage',['$injector', function($injector) {

    this.$get = ['$http', function($http) {  // calling a factory       
        var userLang = getUserLang.getLang()
        return {
            getLang: function() {
                // ....
            }
        }
    }];    

}]);
```

The `$injector` service will automatically append the `Provider` suffix to the configuration object. The configuration object will then be injectable into `.config` functions as the name of the service appended with `Provider` as a suffix.